# Are you allowed to assign an element a ref if the parent component did not pass one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-ref

```
function Parent() {
    const reusableComponentRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <ChildComponent ref={reusableComponentRef}/>
        <ChildComponent2/>
    )
}

interface ChildComponentProps {
    ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>
}

function ChildComponent({ref}: ChildComponentProps) {
    return (
        <ReusableComponent ref={ref}/>
    )
}

function ChildComponent2() {
    return (
        <ReusableComponent/>
    )
}

interface ReusableComponentProps {
    ref?: RefObject<HTMLElement>
}

function ReusableComponent({ref}: ReusableComponentProps) {
    return (
        // am I still allowed to assign a ref to this div?
        //  even though there will be cases where a ref isn't passed by the parent?
        <div ref={ref}> 
            <div>
                Some Text
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Assume my code structure looks like this. I have a parent container component which returns two children components that both use the ReusableComponent. Only one of them is required to pass a ref down to the ReusableComponent and in the props I have set the ref to be an optional parameter.

My question is, would it be valid to assign the ref to the `<div></div>` in ReusableComponent even though there will be cases in the codebase where ReusableComponent will not receive a ref from its parent? I am working on existing code (ReusableComponent) so changing all instances of ReusableComponent to pass a ref is not viable.

Would I have to do something like this?

```
function ReusableComponent({ref}: ReusableComponentProps) {
    const defaultRef = useRef(null);
    const usedRef = (ref === null)? defaultRef : ref;

    return (
        <div ref={usedRef}> 
            <div>
                Some Text
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think you can do that via forword ref like this: 
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would it be valid to assign the ref to the  in ReusableComponent even though there will be cases in the codebase where ReusableComponent will not receive a ref from its parent?

Yes. In this case `ref` will be undefined and its perfectly safe to do `<div ref={undefined}>` .